# Grafics on Thinkpad R50e

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, thinkpad

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Thinkpad R50e, there is no graphics driver, seems to me. The display works, but in a magenta-red mode, video is yellowish, YouTube has no problem. In Details, there is no graphics driver.

Comment: After rather long time I installed Intel® 852GM/855GM x86/MMX/SSE2 as a graphic driver, written in System setting - System -  Details - Graphics   (there is 855GM in machine, I think).   Unfortunatelly, video is still too yelowish, everything else works fine. Looks like " xorg-video-abi-11", and  "xserver-xorg-core" is needed. Any help?